# Monitoring power consumption on Mac

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, power, monitoring

The Android OS monitors the **power consumption of running apps and hardware** (display). As you may guess, this is a useful feature as it allows to track down energy greedy apps.

**Is there an application that would do such monitoring on Mac OS?**

It should calculate the percentages of the charge that an application/process/hardware has used.

I use plenty of little software that runs in the background permanently. It would be nice to know if such little helpers drain the battery significantly.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As of Mavericks, this is provided by the OS. Activity monitor has a tab devoted to displaying the energy use of running (and recently running) apps.

Also, the battery icon shows applications that use significant energy on Mavericks and newer.

Comment: The Battery menu extra in Mavericks will also display the apps using the most energy.

Answer (score 5):

### [iStat Menus](http://bjango.com/mac/istatmenus/)

let's you monitor your current computer power usage. Unfortunately, it does not break it down by app.

Comment: I know - as you said this is not sufficient. It is also proprietary. That's why I'm using the iStat Pro widget.

Answer (score 2):

If you try to catch an app or process that is exceptionally energy-hungry, to the point it annoys MacOS, you can also open the Mac `console` application (in /Applications/Utilities folder) and  select the "Diagnostic Reports" group on the side-bar. high-energy incidents are recorded there, many times with quite detailed information. Each report is for one energy-impact incident. For example [image: sample console log on my Mac]

shows that the 'zoom' application was imposing high energy impact several times (dozens of times to be exact...) This technique is useful for retrospective analysis - not for what's going on NOW on the machine (where Activity Monitor is your friend) but for the long run - to see what apps are better removed from your Mac altogether.